# In Unity, how to copy the end values of a state in one animation clip to another?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

In Unity, how do I copy the states of one animation clip to another? I am interested in moving the camera from one position to the next when switching state.  Is there a way to set up the animation clip whereby the next animation clip automatically picks up where the previous one left off?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move camera when the first animation is almost done, you can use

`animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(playingLayer).IsName(playingAnimation) && animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(playingLayer).normalizedTime >= time`

with time = [0,1]

to check when you should move the camera